# proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)$ is divergent with comparison theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In an exercise I had to prove that the following series is divergent:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right).$$

I did it using Integral test for convergence. My question is: Is it possible to prove that this series is divergent using the comparison theorem? I can most of the time solve these type of exercises with the ratio test, or the root test, but when it comes to using the comparison theorem I never know that to compare the series to.

Comment: Apply the mean value theorem for $x \mapsto \ln(1+x)$ in the interval $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that since
$$
\lim \frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{1/n} = \lim \frac{\frac{-1/n^2}{1+1/n}}{-1/n^2} = 1,
$$

$\sum \ln(1+1/n))$ as the same nature as $\sum 1/n$, hence it is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

You can show easily that $\ln (1+1/n) \sim 1/n$ which is the general term of a positive divergent series, thus your previous series is divergent

But there is a better way to prove it : remark that $\ln(1+1/n) = \ln(\frac{n+1}{n}) = \ln(n+1) - \ln n$, so you have 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln (k+1) - \ln k = \ln (n+1) \to \infty
\end{align}

Comment: You should make that your answer, Dldier_. (Just click on `edit` to edit your answer.)